# libuvc program does not compile

Tags: c++, c, gcc, ld

I'm trying to use libuvc in one of my C/C++ projects. I succesfully compiled and installed both libusb and libuvc from source and when I attempt to compile the following code using gcc:

```
#include "libuvc/libuvc.h"

int main (int argc, const char **argv) {
    uvc_init(NULL, NULL);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_uvc_init", referenced from:
      _main in main-de2855.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm on MacOS High Sierra 10.13.1 x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the command:

```
gcc main.c -luvc -o main
```

and it worked! Adding the `-luvc` flag solved my problem, but I don't understand why I need to use it. I've never needed flags before when working with other C/C++ dependencies.

Comment: you have to link the external dynamic libraries to the binary, for this you will always use `-lname_of_library` or similar.

Comment: `libuvc` depends on `libusb` but I don't need to link the latter. Why is that?